# How do I remove an account, which I already signed out of, from the "Choose an account" page and Android Chrome?

Tags: google-account, chrome-for-android, google

Someone signed-in their Google account on my phone and now I can't get it to disappear from the "Choose an account" list (the one with the "I" icon) on the Chrome browser whenever I access a Google service webpage:

> [image]

I have tried the answers from [WebApps.SE - How to remove accounts from “Choose an account” list in Google sign in?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/123604) without success:

I already signed out of the account, deleted it from Settings > Cloud and Accounts > Accounts on the phone.

I also accessed [accounts.google.com](http://accounts.google.com) where, after clicking my icon on the top right, I get this modal where I can see my signed-in account along with their account with a little text next to it saying "*Session expired*":

> [image]

If I tap on the "Manage accounts" button, I get redirected to a page listing both accounts, an option for incognito and another button "Manage accounts on this device".

[image]

At this point, if I tap on the account I want to remove, it takes me back to *my* account, and if I tap on the "Manage accounts" button, it takes me to my phone settings where, as I previously mentioned, only my account is listed since I signed out and removed the unwanted account:

[image: t]

I also cleared all Chrome app data from the phone's settings but still no luck.

So, apart from changing my phone, how can I get rid of the account?

Comment: The account in the list is just a cosmetic problem. If you select it you are asked for the password. It is just the account name/email that is cached somewhere.

Comment: Not quite entirely cosmetic. Before this, when I landed on that page, it automatically picked up the only account I had and logged me in. I now have to choose which of the two accounts I want to use. Just a minor inconvenience, sure, but I'd still want to be rid of it.